# How to apply a class to ng-container outlet in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

**How can I apply the class "exampleClass" to the content of the container?**

class in **custom.component.scss**:

```
exampleClass {
              backgroundColor: "red";
             }
```

HTML in Component of the **custom.component.html**:

```
            <ng-container
                [ngTemplateOutlet]="customDirective.templateRef"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item, index: i}">
            </ng-container>
```

the HTML where i use it **somewhere.component.html**:

```
<custom-component>
    <ng-template customDirective>
        <div>
            the div i want to apply the class
            // if i apply the class directly here it works, but i dont like this, cause this class is 
            // not part of this component
        <div>
    </ng-template>
</custom component>
```

i also tried to wrap it and change the class - but it wont work:

```
<div class="exampleClass">
    <ng-container
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item, index: i}">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

modified class:

```
exampleClass > div {
                    backgroundColor: "yellow";
                   }
```

Comment: the css needs to go to `custom.component.css` not `custom.component.ts`

Comment: You can try: `.exampleClass ::ng-deep > div { backgroundColor: "yellow";  }` when you wrap it

Comment: @PoulKruijt you are my Hero --> it works! thanks a lot!